# Kafka testcontainer not running

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-test, testcontainers

I am trying to setup an integration test env for debezium integration (following the instructions in this [example](https://debezium.io/blog/2020/03/19/integration-testing-for-change-data-capture-with-testcontainers/)) but the test container (default image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.2.1) doesn't start but throws an exception.

I am using below mentioned code to create a KafkaContainer bean

```
    @Bean
    public KafkaContainer kafkaContainer() {
        if (kafkaContainer == null) {
            kafkaContainer = new KafkaContainer()
                    .withNetwork(network())
                    .withExternalZookeeper("172.17.0.2:2181");

                kafkaContainer.start();
           }
        }

        return kafkaContainer;
    }
```

it throws following exception.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.testcontainers.containers.KafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers(KafkaContainer.java:91)

The following method did not exist:

    org/testcontainers/containers/KafkaContainer.getHost()Ljava/lang/String;

The method's class, org.testcontainers.containers.KafkaContainer, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/home/shubham/.m2/repository/org/testcontainers/kafka/1.14.3/kafka-1.14.3.jar!/org/testcontainers/containers/KafkaContainer.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.testcontainers.containers.KafkaContainer: file:/home/shubham/.m2/repository/org/testcontainers/kafka/1.14.3/kafka-1.14.3.jar
    org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer: file:/home/shubham/.m2/repository/org/testcontainers/testcontainers/1.12.5/testcontainers-1.12.5.jar
    org.testcontainers.containers.FailureDetectingExternalResource: file:/home/shubham/.m2/repository/org/testcontainers/testcontainers/1.12.5/testcontainers-1.12.5.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.testcontainers.containers.KafkaContainer

2020-09-10 01:09:49.937 ERROR 72507 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener
```

Comment: More details, please? What kind of exception? Also, even though you posted a link, it's still better to add a code snippet

Comment: @VitalyChura I have added code snippets and strack trace logs.

Answer (score 0):

Used an older version of org.testcontainers in maven dependencies and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I was going to suggest to try a newer one, but ok, whatever worked)